# ROS Groovy with Gazebo standalone

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

@nkoenig has mentioned that in [my previous question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1265/ros-gazebo-sometimes-crashing-at-launch-groovy/) that I can use standalone Gazebo with ROS Groovy..

So, I am curious how it can be done because I want to use the latest version of Gazebo..
In ROS, I have been launching PR2 in Gazebo by

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_emptyworld.launch
```

If I want to do the same with Gazebo standalone, how can I have the same thing happen?
Obviously, first I launch Gazebo by simply

```
gazebo
```

And then, how do I bring up PR2 and ROS?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1298/ros-groovy-with-gazebo-standalone/) by [jys](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/141/jys/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**EXPERIMENTAL**

Checkout [this simulator_gazebo hydro branch](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/hydro/gazebo).
Despite the branch name, build against groovy.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-urdfdom*
```

Next, checkout [gazebo `deprecated_parser_sdf_1.2_support` branch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/35ef436fc81970b00b07d8cf549f58bf5b0de364/?at=deprecated_parser_sdf_1.2_support) and compile.  This has actually been merged with the latest default tip of gazebo.  Set install target to `/usr`.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/share -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

Lastly, go to the simulator_gazebo groovy overlay, and do a rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2013-06-24**:
Thanks for tip, I will also try it.